# How to add shopping cart contents in cookie in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I have situation where i want to store my whole cart into cookie so that if accidently user closed browser, cart contains the same contents using that cookie.

Right now, i am using codeigniter cart class to contain all the products user added to cart.

```
//array for product details...
$insert_data = array(
  'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
  'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
  'image' => $this->input->post('image'),
        'qty' => 1
);

//add previously defined data to cart....
$this->cart->insert($insert_data);

//assigning whole cart to cookie
$this->input->set_cookie('cart_cookie', $this->cart->contents(),36000);
```

But here, set_cookie method is giving error as it is expecting second parameter to be string...But i want whole cart to be stored..

Any solution with this problem?
Or is there any better solution than cookie?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705487/how-codeigniter-keeps-session-data-even-when-browser-closes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359806/why-the-codeigniter-session-does-not-expire-after-closing-the-browser

Comment: `serialize($this->cart->contents())`